# Scroll to anchor (section of page) in react-router-v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use the  tags to scroll to a part of the page. For example:

```
<Link to="/#first">Go</Link>
...
<div id="first">The first section</div>
```

This does not seem to work with react router v6. The solutions I have found are all for previous versions of react router.

I have found that I can use `reloadDocument` to force the reload and that will work, but I want to implement a smooth scroll down to the element if coming from the same page. I would use refs, but I need to be able to link to these sections from other pages as well.

Comment: [`react-router-hash-link`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) is probably what you want, but unfortunately they haven't updated to support RRDv6 just yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll using JS

So instead of

```
<Link to="/#first">Go</Link>
...
<div id="first">The first section</div>
```

you would have

```
<button 
  onClick={() => document.getElementById('first')?.scrollIntoView()}
>
  Go
</button>
...
<div id="first">The first section</div>
```

Comment: The JS solution works perfectly on React. even if the page is componentized with the id and scroll in different places. also. You could use smooth scrolling: `.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})`

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact solution you can use with react-router but [the example](https://plainenglish.io/blog/creating-a-hash-anchor-link-effect-with-react-router-a63dcb1a9b0e) in this link may help you.

You can also do this using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Link the way Abbas Hussain showed above, and then on the target page use the following useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); // Remove the '#' character from the hash
    if (hash) {
      const element = document.getElementById(hash);
      if (element) {
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Depending on the structure of your "page", you may like to use the location provided by react-router's `useLocation` hook instead of `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

Created a Anchor element. `/#first` Use it as

```
...
<Anchor id={'first'} />
...
```

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

interface AnchorProps {
    id: string;
}

export default function Anchor(props: AnchorProps) {
    const { id } = props;
    const ref = useRef<any>(null);
    const location = useLocation();

    const handleHashChange = useCallback(() => {
        if (location.hash.substring(1) === id && ref.current) {
            // Smoothly scroll to the div
            ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
    }, [id, location, ref]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Initial check
        handleHashChange();
        // Listen for hash changes
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);
        return () => {
            // Cleanup
            window.removeEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);
        };
    }, [handleHashChange]);

    return <div id={id} ref={ref} />;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Link to={{ pathname: "/PATH_NAME", hash: "#first" }}>first</Link>
    {...}
  );
};
```